# Fastest way to query Cassandra? Primary key or partition key?

Tags: cassandra, cql

What is the fastest way to query Cassandra?
I have a table where primary key consists of 3 columns. I query by one of those columns and it is incredibly slow (I query via Spark). Would querying by all 3 be faster?

[image]
I also have a partition key which comprises of two columns. Unfortunately, the column I am using to fetch records for is not one of those in partition key. Could it be slow due to that?

Any insight is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the column I am using to fetch records for is not one of those in partition key. Could it be slow due to that?

**Yes, that is likely why things are slow.**  Although to be fair, Spark is designed to query distributed data stores.  It's not designed to be fast.

So I'm assuming that your PRIMARY KEY definition looks like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY((A,B),C)
```

The reason that querying by `C` is slow, is because Cassandra (Spark) cannot determine which node in the cluster is responsible for the data based on `C`.  Therefore, every node needs to be checked for values of `C` which satisfy your query.

> Would querying by all 3 be faster?

**Yes, querying by all three would likely be faster.**  This is because the partition key is made up of `A` and `B`.  With a partition key based query, in this case, the key values of `A` and `B` are hashed together.  That hash is matched-up against the token ranges that each node is responsible for.  In this way, a target node containing the desired data can easily be determined, and there is no need to check each node for matching values.

> If I were to query by using just 1 column from primary key (Let's say A), that would also be fast right?

No, it would not.  Given the partition key definition of `(A,B)`, the node containing the data cannot be determined by `A` alone.  In fact, as the result sets would likely be larger, querying by `A` would probably be slower than querying by `C`.

Comment: At lest query on `C` should be faster than query on another column - Spark connector will push execution down to Cassandra, so filtering will happen on Cassandra side, not like reading everything into memory & filter on the Spark side...

Comment: If I were to query by using just 1 column from primary key (Let's say A), that would also be fast right? I don't have the liberty to query using two or three columns.

Comment: @Faraz Edit made.

Comment: Hello Aaron, wouldn't querying by clustering key be the fastest? It would return tons of records in just 1 go. I like that. Wouldn't querying by clustering key be the fastest?

Comment: @Faraz not without also including the preceding keys as well.